# FabricJs, Webpack not compiling - Critical dependency

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, fabricjs, electron

I am trying to get FabricJs to work with Webpack and Electron and currently not getting it to work.

```
Failed to compile.

    ./~/bindings/bindings.js
    76:22-40 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

I'm getting that when it is trying to compile the FabricJs with Webpack. Have searched in on Google and Stack Overflow and I haven't found a proper solution for it.

This is all the warnings I recieve when I run the DEV compilin:

WARNING in ./~/bindings/bindings.js
         76:22-40 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

```
     WARNING in ./~/bindings/bindings.js
     76:43-53 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

 WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/compile/index.js
 13:21-34 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

 WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/async.js
 96:20-33 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

 WARNING in ./~/ajv/lib/async.js
 119:15-28 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

In my main.js code this is exactly what is written

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Electron from 'vue-electron'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Store from 'vuex'
import {fabric} from 'fabric'
```

I've tried loading it like import 'fabric' or import fabric from 'fabric/dist/fabric.require' and many other ways and it always gets me the same resul.

And the webpack config file is separated in two files webpack.main.config.js and webpack.renderer.config.js

Here is the content of webpack.main.config.js

```
'use strict'

process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'main'

const path = require('path')
const pkg = require('./app/package.json')
const settings = require('./config.js')
const webpack = require('webpack')

console.log(pkg.dependencies)

let mainConfig = {
  entry: {
    main: path.join(__dirname, 'app/src/main/index.js')
  },
  externals: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {}),
  module: {
    exprContextCritical: false,
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: /camo/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.node$/,
        loader: 'node-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    __dirname: false,
    __filename: false
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app/dist')
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.node'],
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'app/node_modules')
    ]
  },
  target: 'electron-main'
}

module.exports = mainConfig
```

And this is the content of the webpack.renderer.config.js

```
'use strict'

process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'renderer'

const path = require('path')
const pkg = require('./app/package.json')
const settings = require('./config.js')
const webpack = require('webpack')

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const AssetsPlugins = require('assets-webpack-plugin')
const assetsPluginInstance = new AssetsPlugins()

let rendererConfig = {
  devtool: '#eval-source-map',
  devServer: { overlay: true },
  entry: {
    renderer: path.join(__dirname, 'app/src/renderer/main.js')
  },
  externals: Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {}),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: 'css-loader'
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: 'vue-html-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        include: [ path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/src/renderer') ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            include: /camo/
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.node$/,
        use: 'node-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'vue-loader',
          options: {
            loaders: {
              sass: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax=1',
              scss: 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          query: {
            limit: 10000,
            name: 'imgs/[name].[ext]'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          query: {
            limit: 10000,
            name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    assetsPluginInstance,
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css'),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: './app/index.ejs',
      appModules: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
        ? path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/node_modules')
        : false,
    }),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'app/dist')
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'components': path.join(__dirname, 'app/src/renderer/components'),
      'renderer': path.join(__dirname, 'app/src/renderer')
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json', '.css', '.node'],
    modules: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'app/node_modules'),
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    ]
  },
  target: 'electron-renderer'
}


/**
 * Adjust rendererConfig for production settings
 */
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  rendererConfig.devtool = ''

  rendererConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"'
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    })
  )
}

module.exports = rendererConfig
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you install fabric without the optional cairo dependencies (only needed/useful in node)? 
`npm install fabric --no-optional`
(see https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/2775)
My workaround ended up using [script-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader) which does the same thing as including fabric in a <script> tag in the browser (just that you get the benefits of webpack bundling)

`import "!script-loader!../static/fabricjs/fabric.js"
// window.fabric is now loaded`

also, I didn't install fabric over npm (since that again installed the dependencies for node), but grabbed a [custom build](http://fabricjs.com/build/) - although both should work fine.

Comment: Installing with npm and the --no-optional flag worked for me. The import like this: `import {fabric} from 'fabric'`.

The cairo dep does not appear to be needed if you are using this on the front-end. They do not communicate that well

Answer (score 1):

Loading it with script-loader has finally made it work with my setup.

For people using vue + webpack + fabric is also a good idea to put the fabric call inside the mount() method on the components or Vue.